# DatagramSocket.receive causes ANR when I ask for POST_NOTIFICATION permission

Tags: android, kotlin, service, anr

I don't know what might be causing my issue because I didn't really made a lot of changes to it. The changes only involved the `MainActivity`, `AndroidManifest`, and the helper class I made that handle the creation of the `Service`, but somehow `StrictMode` was pointing at some illegal disk reads on other files. Also, the `Service` shouldn't immediately affect the app because I only start it on `MainActivity`'s `onStop` because I just want it to listen to some stuff when the `MainActivity` is died. I think I already fixed the illegal reads warning somehow, but I'm still getting the ANR. `StrictMode` is saying that I have a leak, but `LeakCanary` isn't detecting anything. It did detect 1 thing, but I already fixed it. And still, I'm still getting the ANR occasionally. The last code that runs before I get the ANR is a method that sends UDP, which wasn't giving me any issue previously. I already changed that method's parameters to accept `WeakReference`s, but it didn't really help I think. All my I/O operations are either inside a `lifecycleScope.launch` or in a `Thread`, so I don't know why I should be getting an ANR, on an app that was already running fine previously.

Here's my code:

This is the helper class for creating the `Service`:

```
class ServiceHelper : Service() {
    private val socketHelper = SocketHelper.getInstance()!!
    private var lastShownNotificationId = 1

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent.action){
            Actions.START.toString() -> createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, lastShownNotificationId)
            Actions.STOP.toString() -> stopSelf()
        }

//        socketHelper.start(null)
//        socketHelper.socketRespObservers.clear()
//        socketHelper.socketRespObservers.add { socketResp ->
//            val respArr = socketResp.split(SocketHelper.SOCKET_DELIMITER)
//
//            if (respArr[0] == SocketHelper.SERVER_UDP_HEADER) {
//                processUDPMessage(respArr[1], respArr[2])
//            }
//        }

        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun createAndShowForegroundNotification(yourService: Service, notificationId: Int) {
        val notifBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            "atlantis_service_notif_channel_id")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(yourService.getString(R.string.service_notif_title))
            .setContentText(yourService.getString(R.string.service_notif_content))

        val notification = notifBuilder.build()
        yourService.startForeground(notificationId, notification)

        lastShownNotificationId = notificationId
    }

    enum class Actions{
        START, STOP
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun processUDPMessage(udpCommand: String, udpValue: String) {
        if (udpCommand == SocketHelper.APP_NOTIFICATION) {
            val srvNotif = Gson().fromJson(udpValue, ServerNotification::class.java)
            Log.i(TAG, "service notif: $srvNotif")
        }
    }

    companion object{
        const val TAG = ""
    }
}
```

Then this is that `Socket` helper class:

```
class SocketHelper {
    private val broadcastAddr: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255")
    private lateinit var localBroadcastAddr: InetAddress
    private lateinit var basicSocket: DatagramSocket
    val socketRespObservers = mutableListOf<(String) -> Unit>()
    private var socketResp: String by Delegates.observable("") { _, _, newVal ->
        socketRespObservers.forEach { it(newVal) }
    }
    private lateinit var _ctx: WeakReference<Context>
    
    @Synchronized
    fun start(ctx: WeakReference<Context>?) {
        if(ctx != null){
            _ctx = ctx
        }

        Thread {
            try {
                if(!::basicSocket.isInitialized || basicSocket == null){
                    basicSocket = DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT)

                    val udpPayload = StringBuilder()
                        .append(UDP_HEADER).append(SOCKET_DELIMITER)
                        .append(REQ_SERVER_IP_COMMAND).append(SOCKET_DELIMITER)
                        .append("").toString()

                    basicSendToUDP(WeakReference(udpPayload), getBroadcastAddr())
                }

                while (true) {
                    basicReceiveFromUDP()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                sendSnackbar("Socket Error: ${e.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }.start()
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun basicSendToUDP(payload: WeakReference<String>, iAddr: WeakReference<InetAddress>) {
        Log.i(TAG, "basicSendToUDP")
        Thread {
            try{
                val sendPacket =
                    DatagramPacket(
                        payload.get()!!.toByteArray(),
                        payload.get()!!.length,
                        iAddr.get(),
                        UDP_SERVER_PORT
                    )
                basicSocket.send(sendPacket)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "sendUDP IO Error:", e)
                close("sendUDP IO Error")

                val msgArr = e.message?.split("(")
                var realErrorMsg = ""
                if(msgArr != null){
                    realErrorMsg = msgArr[1].replace(")", "")
                    ///I'm using gorm with my golang server, this is just some error msg parsing essentially
                }

                if(realErrorMsg != ""){
                    sendSnackbar("Network error: $realErrorMsg")
                }else{
                    sendSnackbar("Network error occurred")
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e(TAG, "sendUDP IO Error:", e)
                close("sendUDP IO Error")

                sendSnackbar("Network error: ${e.message}")
            }
        }.start()
        
    @Synchronized
    private fun basicReceiveFromUDP() {
        val receiveData = ByteArray(1024)
        val receivePacket = DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.size)

        basicSocket.receive(receivePacket)

        socketResp = String(receivePacket.data, 0, receivePacket.length)

        val respArr = socketResp.split(SOCKET_DELIMITER)

        if (respArr[0] == SERVER_UDP_HEADER && respArr.size > 3 && respArr[3] != null) {
            sendAck(respArr[3].toInt())
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun sendAck(seqNum: Int) {
        val udpPayload = StringBuilder()
            .append(UDP_HEADER).append(SOCKET_DELIMITER)
            .append(ACK_PAYLOAD_RECEIVED).append(SOCKET_DELIMITER)
            .append(seqNum).toString()

        basicSendToUDP(WeakReference(udpPayload), getBroadcastAddr())
    }

    fun getBroadcastAddr(): WeakReference<InetAddress> {
        return WeakReference(broadcastAddr)
    }
    
    private fun sendSnackbar(message: String){
    //I was suspecting this to be a cause of the ANR, but it doesn't seem to be
//        if(::_ctx.isInitialized){
//            (_ctx as MainActivity).showSnackMessage(message, "SocketHelper")
//        }
    }
    
    fun close(closeReason: String) {
        basicSocket.close()
    }
```

On the call to `basicSendToUDP` inside `sendAck`, that seems to be when/where the ANR mostly gets triggered.

Here's how I added the `Service` to the `AndroidManifest`, also currently commented:

```
<service android:name=".utils.helpers.ServiceHelper"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

I don't know if commenting that helped stop the ANR, because it's not appearing after doing that.

Then this are the code that "fixed" the illegal disk reads:

```
val oldPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads()
try{
    prefHelper = (requireActivity().application as MyApp).prefHelper
    /// do stuff with prefHelper
}finally {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(oldPolicy)
}
```

This is what prefHelper actually looks like

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    ...
    val prefHelper by lazy { PreferenceHelper.customPrefs(this, "atlantis_prefs") }
}
```

Then this is what customPrefs looks like:

```
object PreferenceHelper {
    lateinit var instance: SharedPreferences
    
    fun customPrefs(context: Context, name: String): SharedPreferences {
        if(!::instance.isInitialized){
            instance = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        }

        return instance
    }
}
```

Right now, if I disable/comment out all the code that is related to the `Service` (the ones in `MainActivity` and `AndroidManifest`), I'd still the get the leak warning from `StrictMode`, but it won't result into an ANR. I probably have some issue with my `socket` helper class that I just can't see.

UPDATE:

I think I found a very interesting cause of the ANR. After adding `LeakCanary` to my app, I realized that it asks for `POST_NOTIFICATION` permission. I was almost gonna go crazy that my app that I already commented out the part that asks for that permission, is still asking for it. And also, if I accept that request, that's when the ANR happens

UPDATE:

I tried "disabling" `LeakCanary` as I think the leaks aren't as important right now as the ANR because the leaks are mostly caused by `DataBinding` not releasing `ConstraintLayout` properly and I already added a fix to it (I'm still getting some leak notifications about `ConstraintLayout` but I don't want to spend more time on them right now). I also tried to ask the `POST_NOTIFICATION` permission myself, and well, the ANR appeared again. I got `anrwatchdog` now and it was pointing out to the line with `basicSocket?.receive(receivePacket)` in it. Again, all my code works perfectly if I don't ask for `POST_NOTIFICATION` permission, so I don't know why a permission would break it. Right now, even if I haven't accepted the `POST_NOTIFICATION` permission, `anrwatchdog` would already crash the app saying that `basicSocket?.receive(receivePacket)` would cause an ANR.

UPDATE:

I think I hit a metaphorical gas pipe. I filed an issue in issuetracker and, it's already being looked at by the people from AOSP. Here's the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308998372) to the issue.